# Unicode characters not working

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm really new to Javascript and I heard about unicode characters, but I don't know how they work. I did this:

```
alert("U+00BF");
```

which is the unicode for an upside-down question mark, but for some reason it just alerts the letters "U+00BF". I've tried using unicode characters with a format more like this:

```
alert("/xF3");
```

and those worked, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the first one. Does anyone know?

Comment: Can you make us a fiddle sample for the code. Also i guess its happening because you are either using utf-8 charset, or not using it altogether. Try doing it with utf-16.

Comment: How come `alert("/xF3")` worked? It displays literally the four characters /xF3.

Comment: What I mean by "it worked" is just that the right kind of character showed up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"U+00BF"` in `alert("U+00BF");` is a string of length 6 containing the characters `'U'`, `'+'`, `'0'`, `'0'`, `'B'`, `'F'`. Hence the string `"U+00BF"` is echoed out in the alert.

Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode ,

> You can use the Unicode escape sequence in string literals, regular expressions, and identifiers. The escape sequence consists of six ASCII characters: \u and a four-digit hexadecimal number. For example, \u00A9 represents the copyright symbol. Every Unicode escape sequence in JavaScript is interpreted as one character.

Which means, we need to do:

```
alert("\u00BF");
```

to see the "upside-down question mark" unicode character.

Answer (score 2):

The notation U+00BF is simply a conventional way of emphasing that you are mentioning, in text, a Unicode character by its code number 00BF. It is not an escape notation of any kind in JavaScript.

You can use the character as such,

```
alert("¿")
```

provided that handle the [character encoding issues](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset), as you should anyway.

If, however, you find this simple approach not applicable due to some external constraints, you can use a classic JavaScript escape notation:

```
alert("\xBF")
```

for characters in the range up to U+00FF, or the Unicode-based JavaScript escape notation

```
alert("\u00BF")
```

for characters in the range up to U+FFFF. (For characters beyond that, you need a so-called surrogate pair.)

Note that the special character used in these notations is `\` U+005C REVERSE SOLIDUS, commonly, and originally, called “backslash”, not `/` U+002F SOLIDUS, commonly called “slash”, or sometimes (for emphasis) “forward slash”.